# Trying to build apk in debug mode but failed - REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio

im trying to build the apk of my app to taste it in a real device, but I get this error:

[image]

something with `@react-native async`

I followed this steps: [build apk](https://dev.to/nitish173/how-to-generate-a-debug-apk-in-react-native-1gdg)